# How can I measure the radiant intensity of an infrared LED beam?

Tags: led, infrared

I made an infrared (850nm) light source with a LED and secondary optics to create an oval shape beam and I need to measure the radiant intensity in mW/sr at different angles.
Practically to get a light map of the beam, very much the way a goniophotometer works.

The problem is that I can't find any instrument that works in mW/sr, all are mW/cm2 and these units are not covertable.

I assume it is the same as with measuring visible light in cd, where the distance between the source and detector is known.

So if I use a detector with a known diameter, e.g. 1cm and I place it at say 1m, is there a way to convert mW/cm2 to mW/sr?

Or even better if someone knows about an instrument that can measure directly in mW/sr.

Comment: How many cm^2 are there in a steradian at one meter distance?

Comment: I think 10,000 cm^2

Comment: Good, then you have everything you need to convert.

Comment: Well. it looks too easy. I am sure there is a catch somewhere.

Comment: No catch. Just inverse square law and metric system.

Comment: This is kind of like saying you can't find a speedometer that measures speed, they all only measure how fast the wheels are turning. It's true, but if you know the geometry of the system you can convert angular velocity to linear velocity or angular position to linear position.